# Pass a function input as column name to data.frame function

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a function taking a character input. Within the function, I want to use the data.frame() function. Within the data.frame() function, one column name should be the function's character input.

I tried it like this and it didn't work:

```
frame_create <- function(data, **character_input**){

...
some_vector <- c(1:50)

temp_frame <- data.frame(**character_input** = some_vector, ...)

return(temp_frame)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use, `names` to assign or with `setNames` as `=` wouldn't allow evaluation on the lhs of `=`.  In package functions i.e `tibble` or `lst`, it can be created with `:=` and `!!`

```
frame_create <- function(data, character_input){
    some_vector <- 1:50
    temp_frame <- data.frame(some_vector)
    names(temp_frame) <- character_input
    return(temp_frame)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I used the colnames() function since there were multiple columns to name.

Comment: @3wF23Xyj `colnames` or `names` will work for `data.frame` as `names` in `data.frame` is the same as column name (although it is different in  `matrix`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your requirement for using a function to create a new dataframe column?  If you have a dataframe `df` and you want to make a copy with a new column appended then the trivial solution is:

```
df2 <- df
df2$new_col <- 1:50
```

Example of merging multiple dataframes in R:

```
cars1 <- mtcars
cars2 <- cars1
cars3 <- cars2

list1 <- list(cars1, cars2, cars3)

all_cars <- Reduce(rbind, list1)
```

Comment: It was an example, the function is used to create dataframes and merge them in a for-loop for a bigger dataset.

Comment: OP, Suggest you lay out your larger objective.  Note that `for` loops in R are usually not required.  With R's vectorization paradigm there may be a much simpler solution get you want you want.

Comment: See my edited answer for an example of merging multiple dataframes by rows.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I will work more with lists now and save the columns created in the function in lists and then use the reduce() function. I guess there is an option to join columns instead of rows.

Comment: Re: "I guess there is an option to join columns instead of rows."  `cbind` is the by columns analog of `rbind`.